# Boolean params in Axios get request automatically getting converted to string in server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, mongodb-query

I have a json object which I'm passing as params to axios get api. This is the Json object

```
obj = {
  name: "device"
  value: true,
}
```

And I'm calling the axios get request with the above object like this -

```
  tableFilter = (obj) => {
    console.log(typeof obj.value);
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3200/getFilter/", { params: obj })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };
```

In the above code the type of 'obj.value' shows as 'boolean' in console. Now I handle this request in server side like this-

```
Router.get("/getFilter", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(typeof req.query.value);
      dbase.collection("employee").find(
          { [req.query.filter]: req.query.value },
          { projection: { _id: 0 } })
        .toArray().then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
        });
  }
});
```

'Router' is the express router object and 'dbase' is the mongoclient object of my database(They don't matter to my question). In the above code if I console the object 'value' key it shows type as "String". Why is the boolean automatically getting converted to String?
I need to query mongodb documents based on the field "device: true" So I need boolean value not string.

Answer (score 0):

Axios will put the parameters in the URL when using `get`, so they are passed as text to the server.
You could (on the server side):

- check for the presence of the parameter, if it's NOT present assume value is boolean `false` (careful, as on the other hand, its presence does NOT mean it's boolean `true`)
- if present, check if the value of parameter `value` is string `"true"` (potentially a good idea to lowercase it first, so to avoid any shenanigans due to case difference.
  -> If it is, then assume boolean `true`.
  -> If it is anything else, assume boolean `false`

Comment: How can I see the URL? just for knowledge. And is there no way I can pass a boolean value through get request of axios?

Comment: Your URL will look like this:
`http://localhost:3200/getFilter/?name=device&value=true`. Not too sure where you can see it (I'm not coding the server side like you do), but my best guess is that it's going to be part of the `req.query` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an object or data in axios.get(). It takes only the URL;
If you want to send data in get request via axios, then you must add them as query params.
Your URL should look like this:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3200/getFilter/?name="+name+"&value="+value)
//here name and values are const added dynalically
```

Comment: I'm able to send the object through get. In the above code 'req.query' has my object. But that object has a boolean value which I need to access in server side. but I can only access it in string format. So like Tony said is it not possible to send boolean values to server?

Comment: @dharanikumar yes, whatever you send via the query params, it is always passed as a string. So, when you pass value=true it is actually received by the server as value="true".  But, I don't this it should be a problem in your code. Just check it as string value as if(value==='true') .  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to JSON encode the payload on the client-side and then JSON decode the request payload on the server. It will preserve the Boolean values so you won't see a boolean turned into a string "1" or "true".